# Play Framework 2.3.4 Java Ebean Execution exception[[IllegalStateException: Transaction is Inactive]]

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I use Play Framework 2.3.4, Java8, Ebean.
Ebean transaction code is not working.
Please your help.

Java Code

```
Ebean.execute(new TxRunnable() {  
  public void run() {  

    User user = new User();
    user.id = 1;
    user.save();
  }  
});
```

server error log is

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalStateException: Transaction is Inactive]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is Inactive
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction.commit(JdbcTransaction.java:583) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.api.ScopeTrans.onFinally(ScopeTrans.java:101) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.execute(DefaultServer.java:724) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.execute(DefaultServer.java:709) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.execute(Ebean.java:1264) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

provide transaction scope

```
TxScope txScope = TxScope.requiresNew();

Ebean.execute(txScope, new TxRunnable() {  
  public void run() {  

    User user = new User();
    user.id = 1;
    user.save();
  }  
});
```